# Key error in python dictionary due to " "

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{'"Y"_City,_Arkansas': [<__main__.node object at 0x000002A5800AEF28>], 
 'Abbot_Village,_Maine': [<__main__.node object at 0x000002A5800B30B8>]}
```

I'm using a command line argument to pass the key.

```
N1 = sys.argv[1]
```

Let N1 = "Y"_City,_Arkansas

```
for i in range(0,len(newDict[N1])):
    print("City", newDict[N1][i].city)
```

.city contains the name of another city in the value of that key.

Whenever I run this code, I'm getting the following error.

```
for i in range(0,len(newDict[N1])):
KeyError: 'Y'
```

This is only happening because the key : "Y"_City,_Arkansas has " " (double quotes) in it. It's working fine for every other key.

Comment: This is more of a question for SuperUser... You simply aren't passing the command line arguments correctly.

Comment: @Aran-Fey how else am I supposed to pass it?

Comment: `python your_script.py '"Y"_City,_Arkansas'` should work, for example.

Comment: @Aran-Fey no..  KeyError: 'Y_City,_Arkansas'

Comment: Uh, are you on Windows? Try `python your_script.py \"Y\"_City,_Arkansas`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yeah that worked. Stupid Windows!